# Custom link from External List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, external-list

I've got an external List that consists of `Names` and `ID` numbers. What I'd like to do is to somehow make clicking this List take the user to another page (within our SP environment) based on which record they selected. The URL itself needs the ID number contained within it (Ex: `CustomPage.aspx?user={ID Number}`)

I'm flexible with how this gets implemented as the user is simply interested in being taken to a specific Page when they click the List Item. I've noticed that if you click the ellipses on a specific List Item, one of the options is `View Item`. Even if there was a way to override that behavior/action and send them to the page mentioned above in the same manner, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways.

1. Using SharePoint Designer - Open up the External List and then create a new View Form (Or try setting your already created form as View Page). This will open up the Page and by Default pass the list item `ID`
2. Using jQuery add a dynamic column to the list view. Fill the column with `a` tag and populated query string as required.

   ```
   jQuery('.ms-listviewtable thead tr').append('<td>View</td>');

   jQuery('.ms-listviewtable tr').append('<td><a href="custom.aspx?id=">Click</a></td>');
   ```